# How can I stop an infinite render loop if UseEffect() cannot be used in callback in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-effect

Frontend student here trying to figure out React...
I just can't seem to get a hang on these hooks on React. I am trying to setState within the setArray(). This causes an infinite loop in rendering. React won't allow me to do a callback with useEffect(). I can't seem to figure out how to fix this. How can I pass my newly structured array into the state?

```
   const [yearsArray, setYearsArrayState] = useState([]);    

    timelineData.then((data) => {
                let yearsArrays = [];
                for (let item of data.timelineInfo) {
                    yearsArrays.push(item.year);
                }
                setArray(yearsArrays);
            });

            const setArray = (array) => {
                const passArray = new Set(array);
                const oneOfEachYear = [...passArray];
                setYearsArrayState(oneOfEachYear);
            };
        return (<div>
        {yearsArray.map((item) => (
                                <button
                                    className={style.buttonYear}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        toggle();
                                        setClickedYear(item);
                                        console.log(clickedYear);
                                    }}  >
                        </button>
         </div>);
```

Comment: You have a typo in your return statement. Is that just a typo into the question or is that in your code? Specifically `yearsArray.map((item) => ( ... </div>)`;

Comment: How and where do you execute `timelineData` promise? Add the whole component code.

Comment: Typo was something that i fixed on my code. Doesnt really effect my code here though. I have a component that does the fetch api. In this component i pull the year keys and values into a new array to render them out in to buttons. I cut away the code that i thought was unnecessary for my question to get rid of confusion. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put `timelineData` inside a component mount hook

```
// This effect hook will be executed only once at the component mount
useEffect(() => {
  timelineData.then((data) => {
    let newYearsArrays = [];
     for (let item of data.timelineInfo) {
       newYearsArrays.push(item.year);
     }
     setArray(newYearsArrays);
  });
}, []);
```